# Get Title appended to app name win 10 UWP from code

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, titlebar

I have an app named, "My Notes App", with a window showing a document named "Note 1". I set the Title property to "Note 1". I have done the same using the following code.

```
  ApplicationView appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
  appView.Title = "Note 1";
```

Title bar now shows "Note 1 - My Notes App".But I need to show it title appended to dispaly name like "My Notes App-Note 1". Is it possible to do the same ? If possible how I can do it?

Comment: Nope that wont work. Its going to default back to page name followed by `-Display Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define on the page code behind.

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

This will enclose the complete space of titlebar and you can specify a grid with the title name as you want on top.
Else you will need to extend the TitleBar and create your own custom dependancy to override. Check out this [Tutorial](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/easily-manage-the-title-bar-in-windows-10-apps/)